# Geometry question on quadrilaterals

Tags: geometry

$ABCD$ is a convex quadrilaterals with $P$,$Q$,$R$,$S$, midpoints of sides $AB$,$BC$,$CD$ and $DA$ respectively. Such that triangles $AQR$ and triangles $CSP$ are equilateral.How do I prove that $ABCD$ is a rhombus and find its angles?

Comment: Draw a picture first, maybe that will help.